# Equating the coefficients in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}$$

In the above equation is it possible to equate the coefficients of $\frac{t^k}{k!}$? Or do we need to consider $(\frac{t^k}{k!})^2$? Could you please give me an idea for this?

Comment: Please do not change the text of the question after you have received an answer. I would propose to rollback to the version 2.

Comment: @user I understand. My main question remains the same. I couldn`t write this in the comment box. That was why I wrote the steps for you to show how I did this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equating the coefficients at equal powers of $t$ on both sides one obtains:

$$C_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}C_k.$$

The equating process goes as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k \frac{t^k}{k!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k\frac1{k!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \frac{t^{k+m}}{m!}\\
\stackrel{n=k+m}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k\frac1{k!} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{(n-k)!}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\sum_{k=0}^n C_k \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n C_k \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

The reason for the possibility of the exchange of the summation order in the second line is that both double sums run over the same set of indices: $0\le k\le n<\infty$. It can be seen also from the fact that the summation in both $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n$ formally can run from $0$ to infinity due to $(n-k)!$ term.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If we change the equation as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}$, will the result be the same?

Comment: @SomaWick The result will be similar.  The sum will be only over $k$ with parity different from that of $n$.

Comment: Thank you. But I don`t understand how to get the binomial coefficient part. Could you please help me to understand it?

Comment: @SomaWick I have added an explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: If the equation gets bit different (I mentioned in my question) will the steps be same? I tried to follow your steps. Don`t know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Yes the steps are the same. You rename the running index to $k$ (so that you deal with $C_k$), obtain the overall exponent of $t$ (in that case $m+k$), and let the exponent be $n$ (redefining $m$). At the end you will need to reverse the order of summation. This can be sometimes tricky.

Comment: Can we do the steps like below to equate the coefficients of $\frac{t^n}{n!}$? 

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^{2m+n+1}}{n!(2m+1)!}\\
\stackrel{k=2m+n+1}=2\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=2m+1}^{\infty}  C_{k-2m-1} \frac{t^{k}}{(k-2m-1)!(2m+1)!}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^{2k+1} C_{k-2m-1} \frac{t^{k}}{(k-2m-1)!(2m+1)!}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^{2k+1} C_{k-2m-1} \binom{k}{2m+1} \frac{t^{k}}{k!}.$$

Comment: @SomaWick In the last two sums $m$ should run up to $\left\lfloor{\frac{k-1}{2}}\right\rfloor$ (but really it does not matter because the binomial coefficient for all "excessive" terms is 0). Otherwise looks nice.

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}
$

Here's how you get 
the binomial coefficients.

Note:
These are called exponential generating functions
because of their similarity to
$e^t
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty C_n \frac{t^{n+m}}{n!m!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^k C_n \frac{t^{k}}{n!(k-n)!}
\qquad n+m = k, m = k-n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^k C_n \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^k C_n \binom{k}{n}\\
\end{array}
$